# Restoring Arabian Jasmine

Tags: bud

I live in Punjab, Pakistan. The temperature is warm to hot for most of the year. There is bright sunlight in my city for probably 320 days in a year. The soil is quite fertile and rich of natural nutrients.

Near about September 2019, I bought 3 plants of Arabian Jasmine to start a new hobby. It is fairly common here, a lot of home lawns have it and sometimes I have seen its dense bushes 3-4 feet wide and similarly tall. I kept the plants in local soil, packed in wooden crates lined with plastic woven sacks. The crates are placed on the roof in a position that the get sunlight all day. My plants were doing fine. I watered them almost every day, with some days missed out when the soil was already wet. I gave each of them 10-15 grams of NPK fertilizer once a week. The plants grew new flowers once or twice a month.

The winter season went quite hard on my plants. Sometimes I couldn't water them for 8-10 days in a row and the temperature fell as low as 2 'C on some days. In Feb 2020, I started to take care of the plants again and give them water and fertilizer regularly.

Now after more than a month, one of the plants hasn't grown anything new and it's branches are completely brown and dry, with not a single leaf left. I think it has died out. The other two plants are growing new buds and I want to recover them as much as possible.

I have noticed that there are some (8-10) old buds still remaining on the plants, which are either completely or partially brown. So I took a few pictures and tried to classify the buds and branches.

1. New buds, green.
2. Old buds with brown leaf tips.
3. Old buds with completely brown and crispy leaves. On green or brown branches.
4. Green branches with Type 2 or 3 buds.
5. Brown, crack-able branches.

Please see the attached pictures and try to answer the following questions. Any other advice is also always welcome. If you think I have some wrong concept anywhere, please feel free to correct me.

1. Some of the buds are completely green. I hope they grow into new branches and leaves. They are spurting from joints and from the middle of the branches. How can I ensure their continued growth and promote formation of new buds?
2. Some of the buds have leaves with brown ends. I understand these may have faced shortage of water some time ago. Can these buds grow back to normal life? How can I restore them?
3. Some of the buds are completely brown and crispy. They fall off if I touch them firmly. They are probably dead. Some of these are on green branches and some are on brown, dried branches. If I break these buds off, will new buds grow in their place?
4. Some of the branches are green but they don't have any grown leaves on them, just type 2 or 3 buds. Are these branches likely to grow?
5. Some of the branches are brown and dried. If I break them off their joint from the preceding green part, is there a chance a new branch or bud will grow in their place?

[image: My setup on the rooftop]
[image: Mixed buds on a joint]
[image: Old and new buds]
[image: old buds]
[image: green branch with no leaves and a few pairs of buds]
[image: a good bud in the middle of the stem]

Answer (score 1):

Just remove any completely dead stems back to where they are live, and shorten any other long, straggly stems back to where there is a growth bud to encourage a more bushy plant, since you're not growing it as a climbing plant. You cannot revive any buds which have died over winter, but so long as the stem is not dead, it will put out new buds over time. You need not worry about trying to remove little buds that may or may not be fully dead - if they're dead, they will fall off eventually on their own.

Comment: Thanks. I understand.